# Using a Data Structure for Rock, Paper, Scissors

Tags: java

Due to time constraints when it came to coming up with an idea for an assignment, I decided to choose rock, paper, scissors. I have to implement a rock, paper, scissors program in Java using either queues, stacks, heaps, trees, graphs, or search trees. What do you think would be the best method for this situation? I am leaning towards using queues but I would like to hear some input.

Comment: what on earth are you going to store in the list or whatever

Comment: Why would you need any of those data structures?  What is your program supposed to do?

Comment: I guess if you have to force a data structure into your program you could make a class that has "Rock" "Paper" "Scissors" as static constants and stores String player 1 and player 2 as not static constants then you could use a map to store the game number to what the players played.

Comment: Using these structures was a requirement. I was caught up in other projects so I had to come up with the first thing I could think of by a certain date and that's what came to mind. Make a rock, paper, scissors game using swing and one of the structures mentioned in the question. Like I said, chose it because of lack of time.

Comment: You need to decide what you are going to store and why before you pick a data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really much of a call for *any* of those data structures in a simple game like Rock, Paper Scissors.

I suppose you *could* use a queue to store individual results so you canm tally them up at the end rather than keeping a running total of wins, losses and draws in three simple variables.

Or you could maintain statistics in a tree, detailing what the user tended to choose after each run. For example, to pick out patterns like "user chooses rocks after paper 73% of the time" or "there's an inordinately large number of 'rock-rock-scissors' sequences". This may allow your algorithm to adjust to behavioural characteristics of its opponent.

But, in all honesty, I think your choice of game was ... ill-advised (pax said tactfully). My advice would be to go back to your educator and state that flat out, asking if you could change it to something more suitable. You'll probably find they're happy to accommodate you if you show the intestinal fortitude to admit you were wrong.

And, next time, don't leave your run so late. The path through the IT industry is littered with the bodies of those who, while technically adept, couldn't manage their time well enough to just get stuff *done* :-)